# Does library scaleogram have inbuilt 'rbio' wavelet? I have to analyze an ECG signal with rbio wavelet and perform cwt and plot a scaleogram

Tags: python, spectrogram, wavelet, wavelet-transform

This is the code I am using. Works for 'morl', 'gaus', 'mexh', but not for 'rbio'.

```
scg.set_default_wavelet('mexh')
scg.cws(data[:signal_length], coi = False);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse biorthogonal wavelets are only compatible with the **Discrete Wavelet Transform**.

You can list wavelets compatible with the **Continuous Wavelet Transform** by using the 'continuous' kind in pywt's `wavelist` function:

```
import pywt
print(pywt.wavelist(kind='continuous'))
```

This returns: ['cgau1', 'cgau2', 'cgau3', 'cgau4', 'cgau5', 'cgau6', 'cgau7', 'cgau8', 'cmor', 'fbsp', 'gaus1', 'gaus2', 'gaus3', 'gaus4', 'gaus5', 'gaus6', 'gaus7', 'gaus8', 'mexh', 'morl', 'shan']

Comment: Thanks. Can db2 level 4 be used for cwt?

Comment: No. Daubechies wavelets are meant to be used with the DWT.

Comment: I would like to use rbio 3.1 wavelet for wavelet decomposition, in order to enhance a particular wave in ECGs. I am using "pywt.wavedec(signal,'db2', level=4)". Seems to work for Daubechies but displaying unknown wavelet for rbio. Could you pls clarify this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `wavedec` is used to perform a DWT. Please check the output of `pywt.wavelist(kind='discrete')`: you can see that `rbio` is not listed. Instead, you can see the following wavelets: 'rbio1.1', 'rbio1.3', 'rbio1.5', 'rbio2.2', 'rbio2.4', 'rbio2.6', 'rbio2.8', 'rbio3.1', 'rbio3.3', 'rbio3.5', 'rbio3.7', 'rbio3.9', 'rbio4.4', 'rbio5.5', 'rbio6.8'. Using those in `wavedec` should work (`e.g.` pywt.wavedec(signal,'rbio6.8', level=2))!